# Custom Form Update Best Practices

Tags: custom-list, custom-form

This is a general question on how deploying a custom Visual Studio form to a SharePoint list works.

My understanding is that custom forms can be added to an existing list definition or to list definition defined in the Visual Studio project. What happens if you need to make a change to an existing form that has been deployed to a farm? Can you simply do an "update-spsolution" and expect the form to be updated?